# multiple tabs console log file for chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I need to log the console output on two chrome tabs in a logging file.
I did start the chrome browser via --enable_logging --v=1 options from command line. But I am not sure the file found in Default folder(chrome_debug.log)  corresponds to which tab or if chrome saves two console logging files for two tabs. How do I find that out ?

Comment: I have closed and opened chrome via command line( google-chrome --enable_logging --v=1) multiple times. But I don't see the chrome_debug.log file changing. It still stores the information of the very first chrome session. Also there are no multiple log files for multiple tabs. I am thinking it might be a bug with chrome.